# How to create a random increment that is a multiple of 5?

Tags: c#

I create a random Time `randomTime` between two TimeSpans using

```
Random random = new Random();
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.FromHours(StundenS);
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.FromHours(StundenE);
int maxMinutes = (int)((end - start).TotalMinutes);
int minutes = random.Next(maxMinutes);
TimeSpan randomTime = start.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));
```

If `StundenS` = `10` and `StundenE` = `11`, the result could be `10:51`, which is correct. Yet how do I make it change in 5 minute increments instead of 1 minute increment, so `10:51` is forbidden, `10:50` is not and `10:55` is not either?

EDIT: I solved it with

```
minutes = (int)(Math.Round((double)minutes / 5) * 5);
TimeSpan randomTime = start.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));
```

Comment: multiply a whole number by 5.

Comment: @DanielA.White multiply which whole number by 5?

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Math.Round(minutes / 5.0) * 5)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I had the same idea right at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Reduce your range and multiply.

It is very easy to get a random integer between two values (say, 0 and 10). In such a case 10 discrete values are possible outcomes.

Now that I can only get one of 10 numbers, I can multiply to get the correct scale. So to get any multiple of 10 from 0 to 100 I could write:

```
int rand = random.Next(0, 10);
int scaledRand = rand * 10;
```

If I then wanted values between 50 and 150 (still that 100 range notice) you simply add:

```
int finalRand = scaledRand + 50;
```

Similarly, you have a range of 60 with multiples of 5. Dividing gives a requirement of 12 discrete values so the code:

```
int rand = random.Next(0, 12);
int scaledRand = rand * 5;
```

Gives you the multiples you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the random.Next an array which consists of increments of 5s.

```
int[]  array = new int {5,10,15,...,55};
int minutes = random.Next(0, array.Length);
int randomnumber = array[minutes];
```

Comment: This is prohibitively difficult for a large range. Not a recommended method though the only one that works if the desired set does not follow a pattern.